# setInterval(function() and updateVars() for many carousels

Tags: jquery, owl-carousel

Currently I have the following in my `$(document).ready(function()` AFTER the initialization for the sliders themselves.

This code represents 3 sliders and it works, but I have more sliders.

- *When I add more than 4-5+ sliders then it doesn't work (it works on some, not others)*

**Is there a way to add a bunch of sliders here?**

```
 setInterval(function(){

   var owldataTS = $(".testimonial-slider").data('owlCarousel');
   owldataTS.updateVars();

   var owldataMS = $(".multi-slider").data('owlCarousel');
   owldataMS.updateVars();

   var owldataMM = $(".mini-multi").data('owlCarousel');
   owldataMM.updateVars();


},1500);
```

BTW: this is used for when a page size changes without a re-size of the viewport, like toggling a sidebar or tab content.

Comment: Are you sure you are giving the correct and unique DOM elements for carousel to apply?

Comment: @RahulPatil - yes. Unique variables pointing to specific initializations of the carousels by class name. Is that what you mean? I am not a great one with jQuery/js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can give a common class for the sliders and do:

```
setInterval(function(){
 $(".common-class").each(function(){
    $(this).data('owlCarousel').updateVars();
 });
},1500);
```

Comment: I tried that, they all have a common class and it didn't work. But I will give it a shot again once I clear my cache and get some food. Perhaps I'm just sleepy

Comment: Yes, I will do that (a non-working Fiddle) when I get back from getting my daughter far away. I tried what you just posted and when the sliders are on different pages, it works, but when they are on the same page, it only does it to the first instance of the slider. But when I specify the classes specifically, then it works, but only up to about 3 in each setInterval(function().

Comment: @Christina jQuery won't iterate over the collection while using getter methods... try manually iterating..

Comment: This last one, the update works freaking great! I will test on my other pages too.

Comment: Amazing! You are brilliant.